# Is: "put up by someone" a correct phrasal verb?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

> A great performance put up by the autistic children.

Is this sentence correct? Because I cant find the phrasal verb's meaning anywhere.

Comment: We normally say "put **on**" a show or performance.

Comment: If I google "put up", the very first thing that I get is a definition of what it means.

Comment: "put up" isn't used in this way in American English - it does seem like it is used that way in British or Indian English though.

Comment: As a BrE native speaker, I can attest that "put up" is not commonly used in this way in BrE either. See my newly edited answer for an analysis of the distinction.

Comment: @Σωκράτης Looking over the [results of a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22performance+put+up%22&ia=news) it seems like the references I saw in UK news were actually reported speech from folks of other nationalities. I think it may be Indian English, but I saw some African sports-related references as well. I wonder where the Aussies fall  :)

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=aJUXAAAAIAAJ&q=%22put+up+a+performance%22&dq=%22put+up+a+performance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ-6i-6a_MAhUJn4MKHfB8DeMQ6AEIHTAA

Comment: @Ardis Ell: you have not given us a sentence but a sentence fragment.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing at all unusual about *putting up an [adjective] performance*. From Google Books...

> *put up a great performance* [(256 results)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put%20up%20a%20great%20performance%22)
>    *put up a strong performance* [(391 results)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put%20up%20a%20strong%20performance%22)
>    *put up a poor performance* [(257 results)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put%20up%20a%20strong%20performance%22#tbm=bks&q=%22put%20up%20a%20poor%20performance%22)
>    etc., etc.

To the extent that there's a difference between ***up*** and ***on*** in such contexts, *to put **on** a performance* usually alludes to *performance = show, public spectacle* (i.e. - it's about ***entertainment***). In contrast, *to put **up** a [good/bad] performance* usually refers to how well or badly someone did in a competitive context (which might not necessarily be intended to entertain, or even be particularly "public").

Effectively equivalent to *put up a strong performance* is [*put up a strong **showing***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put%20up%20a%20strong%20showing%22) (222 results).

---

Note that OP's specific example would more naturally be phrased as...

> *The autistic children put up a great performance.*

...but that doesn't mean there's anything "wrong" with the stylistic choice to re-order the words.

Comment: The fact that you can find Google attestations is not an indication that there is "nothing at all unusual" about the locution. It is not the usual locution in BrE or AmE. It often doesn't mean quite the same thing as **put on**.

Comment: @TRomano: Not sure how to interpret that comment. I say there's nothing unusual about the usage because *I'm perfectly familiar with it*, not because I can find supporting examples in Google Books. If you're not then perhaps there's a US/UK divide here, but I make a very clear distinction between *putting **on** a good performance* (staging a "show" that was entertaining to spectators), and *putting **up** a good performance* (performing bravely, acquitting oneself well in a "challenging" context).

Comment: I am familiar with both, and concur with your distinction, **put up** referring to how well you have acquitted yourself, and **put on** referring to the outward show or spectacle. Although at first it seemed to me that the OP's example referred to a children's stage play,  as I reconsidered, it doesn't really give us enough context to say which of these two locutions would be the idiomatic one in GenE.

Comment: @TRomano: Well, given the defining characteristic of *autistic* children is that they're not good at seeing things from others' perspectives, I pretty much take it for granted that they wouldn't be much good at *entertaining* an audience with a "show". Therefore to me it seems natural to assume the intended sense is that ***despite not being naturally equipped*** for "performing", they "put up a good showing" (they did well *on their terms*, even if what they achieved wasn't exceptional by normal standards). Why else would OP specifically mention ***autistic*** children?

Comment: Involving kids with autism in dramatic skits is a way to have them learn to recognize and portray emotions, so that's where my mind went.

Comment: http://www.buzzingbubs.com/bangalore/the-lion-king-a-unique-stage-play-by-autistic-children   "It is the first time that autistic children put up a public performance with fairly complex themes to a large crowd. "  (InE)

Comment: @TRomano: oic. "Indian English" then. By normal standards, practically every other sentence on that page is "defective" in one way or another. In that specific context, *It **was** the first time that autistic children **had** put **on** a public performance* would be far more "natural". But that should be clear from my answer anyway *(to **put on = stage** a performance)*, particularly bearing in mind that the source itself uses the verb ***to stage*** several times, and at least they get *that* right).